# LightTable IDE legacy REPL mode?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, lighttable

I found
[Light Table](http://www.lighttable.com/)
is a great tool to try Clojure language.

It has a handy feature called Instarepl -

;; Anything you type in here will be executed immediately with the results shown on the right.

However, I can't find a way to use a legacy REPL mode which I can run a small code such as

```
(take 100 (iterate inc 1))
```

Typing the code, sure the Instarepl immediately eval and show

```
(1 2 3 4 5 ...)
```

, but does not exactly shows the result.

Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, on a second try, I found out that clicking the animated-blue-block-icon shows a bottom pane (console), into which for example println outputs. This was what I needed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Light Table uses leining for the project management, so you can very easily keep repl open in another window connected to the same project to get the traditional REPL expierence. This lets you switch between the two quickly. Light Table is evolving rapidly and who knows if standalone repl mode has been added since I last looked or will be added soon.